# In asp.net mvc, how to add validations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-validation

I want to compare passwords and also a specified password length. There is some problem in the controller where I am updating it, it returns view only if the passwords are empty, then I applied condition to match them, but I want this to be done automatically like when I want to check the length I don't wnt to apply another condition in model. Please help me what is the problem with my approach?

I have tried this code

Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPass()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ResetPass(userPass model, string phoneNumber, String password, String repassword)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.repassword) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.password)&&model.password==model.repassword )
        {
            using (var db = new MongoContext())
            {
                db._database.GetCollection<userPass>("userPass");

                var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_phoneNumber", phoneNumber);

                var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
                    .Set("password", password);

                db._database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("farmers").UpdateOne(filter, update, null);

                return RedirectToAction("Login", new {Message = "password has been reset"});
            } 
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class userPass
    {
    [BsonElement("password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Password length must be 8.")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("repassword")
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirmation Password is required.")]
    [Compare("password", ErrorMessage = "Password and Confirmation Password must match.")]
    public string repassword { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
              @using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPass", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password</td>
                            <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.password)</td>
                            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.password, "", new { @class = "error" })</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Confirm Password</td>
                            <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.repassword)</td>
                            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.repassword, "", new { @class = "error" })</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block m-b" value="Submit" /></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                }

                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPass(userPass model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {

    }
    return View(model)
}
```

Just a little bit of modification.

For Minimum Length you can use range attribute -

```
[Range(8, 25, ErrorMessage = "Min Length should be 8")]
```

First paramter is minLength and second is maxLength

or

```
[MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Min Length should be 8")]
```

Comment: Now it's working for comparing without writing condition in the controller and for required but not for the string length.

Comment: @artista_14 It's not `Range`, its `StringLength`, OP just has to define `MinimumLength`

Comment: @renu you're not providing `MinimumLength`

Comment: agree with @EdSF. you can use MinimumLength also

Comment: @artista_14 I can't upvote, this notification is displayed:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 1):

Edit compare attribute.

```
 [Compare(CompareField = password, ErrorMessage = "Password and Confirmation Password must match.")]
```

here is detail example :

```
 public class userPass
 {
    [BsonElement("password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Password length must be 8.")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("repassword")
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirmation Password is required.")]
    [Compare(CompareField = password, ErrorMessage = "Password and Confirmation Password must match.")]
    public string repassword { get; set; }
```

}